# Return certain part of string mysql

Tags: mysql

I am fetching results from a database table which contains the text of multiple pages.

These pages have links in their content.

I am trying to get all the links from the pages in a table, but I am also getting the unwanted text.

For example, this could be the content of a certain part of a page: 
line 1: `This is the link for lalalaal     </a href="page5.html"> click</a>`
line 2 `if you want to go to page lalalala2 <a href="page6.html"> click</a>`

Now I only want the  area starting from the `<a href` and ending at `</a`>  in the result record. if there are more than 1 anchor tags in the text, then each anchor tag should be treated as a record.
the returned result should be like
ID              value
1               ' click '
2               ' click '

I have tried the following queries :

1. Select * from [Database.tablename] where value between `<a href`  and `</a>`;
2. Select * from [Database.tablename] locate '(`<a href`, Value)>0' and locate (`</a>`, value)>0;

but none of the 2 queries are giving me the wanted result...

Comment: Please edit your post to include some sample text and the queries that you have implemented so far to solve it.

Comment: Still not working any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This sort of text extraction is probably best addressed using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

MySQL has some support (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)), but it could only be useful to identify which rows do have an `<a></a>` pair. Even identifying that there is **at least one** link inside a record doesn't help you **extracting** the (possibly many) links and treating them as different records themselves.

To successfully extract those links, at least according to my knowledge, you need a tool better suited to work with regular expressions. Most languages (Perl, PHP, Python, Java, etc.) support them, some natively, some using available libraries. You can select only records containing links (using `REGEXP`), and extract every link via code.

Another way of handling this would be performing the query on MySQL, exporting the results to a text file, and working on its contents with shell scripting (for instance, using `sed` under UNIX/Linux).

If you need it to be implemented using **only** MySQL, then my best guess is trying with a stored procedure (to be able to work on the results record-by-record.) I still cannot think of an implementation of such SP that guarantees detecting and successfully extracting every possible link inside a record as one record per link.